# Can I use json_array_length with a conditional?

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I have a field with JSON that I'm querying:

A sample data point of field json_data looks like:

```
apples=
[{"CHAR_STARS":1,"CHAR_A1_LVL":1},
{"CHAR_STARS":1,"CHAR_A1_LVL":2}]
```

I can get the count of apples with `json_array_length(json_data['apples'])` which returns 2 in this case

What is I wanted to only count those with CHAR_A1_LVL > 1? This would return 1 in this case.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your JSON data has a regular schema, you can convert it to an `array(row(char_stars bigint, char_a1_lvl bigint))` and use [`filter`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#filter) with a [lambda expression](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/lambda.html) to select the elements that match the desired condition.

For example:

```sql
WITH data(x) AS (
    VALUES '[{"CHAR_STARS":1,"CHAR_A1_LVL":1}, {"CHAR_STARS":1,"CHAR_A1_LVL":2}]'
)
SELECT cardinality(
    filter(
        cast(json_parse(x) as array(row(char_stars bigint, char_a1_lvl bigint))),
        r -> r.char_a1_lvl > 1))
FROM data;
```